# eigen vector and values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a linear operator defined on $D(A) \subset \mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ and  $$B=\prod_{k=1}^n \left(A-\lambda_kI \right)$$, where $I$ is identity. Let $x$ be a vector such that $Bx=0$. Does it imply that $$\left(A-\lambda_kI \right)x=0$$ for some $k \in \lbrace 1,2, \dots, n \rbrace$ ?

Comment: No. $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\vec{0}$, but none of the two matrices multiplied by $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is zero.

Comment: I thought of the same example, but I figured that maybe infinite dimension changes something ?

Comment: @rafalpw infinite dimensional spaces have operators of finite rank.  If a counterexample works in finite dimensional space, it will definitely work in infinite dimensional space.

Comment: The statement, if it were true, would mean that the Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that every vector is an eigenvector.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I asked this, because I have a problem. I have a matrix B of this form and it's not 1-1 in $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$. I want to find out if it's 1-1 in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ and it turns out that for $ 0 \neq x \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ I have that $\left(A-\lambda_kI \right)x\neq 0$ . And I was wondering if it's at least somewhat close to proving 1-1 for B in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$

Comment: Is $\Bbb C^\infty$ just the space of infinite sequences?

Comment: I think you should post your problem as a separate post.

Comment: Yes. $F^{\infty}=\lbrace \left(x_1,x_2, \dots \right) : x_i \in F) \rbrace$

Comment: Given your hypothesis, I think that you can show that $x$ is a linear combination of vectors in the kernel of $(A - \lambda_k I)$ for $k = 1,\dots,n$

Comment: OKay, I'll try something and meanwhile I'll start a new topic as suggested.